# Is margin bleeding a bug in WebKit?

Tags: css, html, webkit, render

I am not sure if this is a bug or there is some arcane CSS rule at play here.
Basically, a margin setting on a child element will be effectuated outside its parent even when the parent is big enough to accommodate the child and it's margins completely.

Here's a small HTML document that demonstrates this: https://gist.github.com/skid/5048988.
This happens on Chrome 25, but not on Firefox 14.

Comment: working as intended: see [Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing)

Comment: Yes, but the container *is bigger* in height than the child + child's margin. Firefox does not behave like this.

Answer (score 1):

[From @Yosyhi comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing) :
Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

Margin collapsing occurs in three basic cases:

- Adjacent siblings
- Parent and first/last child
- Empty blocks